# Fetching in a VSCode extension: node-fetch and node:http issues

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, node-fetch

I am very very new to VSCode extension development. So this may be a trivial question or something that already been discussed. But I can't get to make it work. So I am seeking out help.

I have a very simple extension that I am building at the moment. With a command from the command pallet (Let's say: `Light Me Up`) it will show a random quote as an information message.

This is what I want to do. I want to fetch a bunch of quotes from [here](https://zenquotes.io/api/quotes) and then store them in a variable and then each time the command is fired I want to select a random one and show it.

This is my code is looking like

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
// const got = require('got');

// this method is called when your extension is activated
// your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "seecode" is now active!');

    let data;

    (async () => {
        const response = await fetch("https://zenquotes.io/api/quotes");
        data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    })();

    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.commands.registerCommand('seecode.helloWorld', () => {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello from SeeCode! See you on the other side');
            }
        )
    );

    

    // context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('seecode.'));
}
```

And this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "seecode",
  "displayName": "SeeCode",
  "description": "Easy Visual DevOPs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.63.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:seecode.helloWorld",
    "onCommand:seecode.lightMeUp"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "seecode.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      },
      {
        "command": "seecode.lightMeUp",
        "category": "SeeCode",
        "title": "Light Me Up"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run package",
    "compile": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "package": "webpack --mode production --devtool hidden-source-map",
    "compile-tests": "tsc -p . --outDir out",
    "watch-tests": "tsc -p . -w --outDir out",
    "pretest": "npm run compile-tests && npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/glob": "^7.1.4",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/node": "14.x",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.63.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.1.0",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^1.6.2",
    "eslint": "^8.1.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.7",
    "mocha": "^9.1.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.5",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "webpack": "^5.52.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

when I try to run the extension it opens up the second VSCode window but then if I try to issue any command from here (Let's say the `Hello World` one) then it gives me the following error

```
Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.seecode' failed: 
Cannot find module 'node:http' Require stack: 
- /home/shubhadeep/work/personal/vscode_extension/seecode/dist/extension.js
- /snap/code/85/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js
- /snap/code/85/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/bootstrap-amd.js
- /snap/code/85/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/bootstrap-fork.js.
```

What do I do to fix this? I just want to see the json in the console. Wham am I missing here?

Comment: is `node-fetch` missing a required module: `node-http`

Comment: I would think so, but I can't find the logic. Shouldn't it automatically install it when getting installed by itself?

Comment: does it work if you create a NodeJS script (JavaScript or TypeScript) in the same workspace with the `fetch` and `console.log`

Comment: So yes, when I write one of the example code from `node-fetch` github page in a separate JS file, and then change the package.json to add `"type": "module"` and then run the file like so - `node file_name.js` it works without any issue...

Comment: And also, my exact code, copy pasted from the extension.ts (the entry point for VSCode extensions) to my separate JS file, works as well. What am I missing here?

Comment: do you get the error if you comment the line `import fetch from 'node-fetch';`? or try https://stackoverflow.com/a/63305998/9938317

Comment: The `""@types/node"` has already been added to the `devDependencies` from the start, as I generated the package skeleton using `yo code` (the official way). And it not solve the problem at all. I am really at a loss here. Not sure where am I making a mistake.

Comment: the version of `@types/node` is `14.x` what if you remove the `.x`, have you looked in `node_modules` if you have the module, have you looked at the code Typescript generates, what if you handcraft the Typescript output (that is what is actually run)

Comment: Try downgrading `node-fetch` to v2:  uninstall it and  `npm install -s node-fetch@2`

Comment: This worked!! @Mark . Amazing! Thanks a lot. But it shows an error where I am importing it. The error is this - `Could not find a declaration file for module 'node-fetch'. `

Comment: Try `npm install -s @types/node-fetch` to see if that helps that error.  Apparently the types were included in v3 but not v2.

Comment: It didn't make it go. But for the moment I am not bothered by this error. I thank you again for the help :)

Comment: Maybe `npm install @types/node-fetch@2` is better?  Just a guess.

Comment: You are awesome :) @Mark that did make the error go! I did - `npm install -D @types/node-fetch@2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from these two issues:

[Cannot find module 'node:http` on AWS Lambda v14](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1367)  and
[Problem with importing node-fetch v3.0.0 and node v16.5.0](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1266)

it looks like the upgrade from `node-fetch` v3 to v3.1 was "troublesome" and resulted in the error you are seeing for some.

A few users are downgrading to v2 (or you might try v3 rather than v3.1 which you are using).

Uninstall `node-fetch` and
`npm install -s node-fetch@2`

---

As noted in the comments if you downgrade to v2 you may want to do

`npm install -D @types/node-fetch@2` as well.

---

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above. it worked. It is showing me a strange error at the import statement. But it woks nonetheless. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @SRC maybe `npm i --save-dev @types/node-fetch` helps